# Check if a string contains any element of array

Tags: javascript, node.js

Say I have a string as:

```
const subject = "This process is flawless"
```

and I have an array as:

```
const matchArray = ["process","procedure","job"]
```

I want it such that if subject contains any keyword from matchArray,

```
if (subject matches any keyword of matchArray ){

console.log('true')
}
```

My first instinct was to use includes but I don't want to match array with a string but instead string with an array.

I'm still exploring, if anyone could guide me that would be reall helpful.

**Edit: I found this soultion, but is there any better solution than this**

```
const subject = "This process is flawless"
const matchArray = ["process","procedure","job"]
const exists = matchArray.some(matchArray => subject.includes(matchArray))

if (exists) {
  console.log("Yes");
  // notify 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

```js
const subject = "This process is flawless"
const matchArray = ["process", "procedure", "job"]

console.log(matchArray.some(i => subject.includes(i)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code if you want to check separately each index of array if it is present or not

```
const subject = "This process is flawless"
const matchArray = ["process","procedure","job"]
const subject_array=subject.split(" ");
console.log(subject_array);// split the string by space
// loop on matchArray matchArray
for(i=0;i<matchArray.length;i++){
const c_string=matchArray[i];
var check = subject.includes(c_string);
if(check==true){
 console.log(c_string,' is present');
    }
  }
```

[Here is the out put](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NgCUf.png)